# Category with pullbacks

Tags: category-theory

If $C$ is a category such that every square is a pullback then is every morphism in $C$ invertible? I don't know whether it's true or not. If it's true I can try proving it.

Answer (score 3):

Yes this is true. Let $f:Y\rightarrow X$ be any morphism in $C$. Then form the commutative square
$$ \require{AMScd}\begin{CD}Y@>{f}>>X \\ @V{f}VV@|\\X@=X\end{CD}$$
If all square is a pullback, then $f$ is a pullback of an isomorphism, hence an isomorphism.